# Watchman: Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Not a directory

Tags: ios, react-native, watchman

I'm trying to run a basic react native project (tutorial) on Mac, but when running emulator or deploying to a device I'm getting this:

```
Error: watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code null 2016-11-09T23:34:15,970: [cli] Failed to open /Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Not a directory
```

I tried to reinstall watchman from git `brew install --HEAD watchman` but it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to use HEAD of watchman as it exists today, as it is currently under very active development; stick with the stable version that is in homebrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was I had a file ~/Library/LaunchAgents pointing to homebrew.mxcl.postgresql instead of the folder.
So I just moved homebrew.mxcl.postgresql to a temp folder, deleted ~/Library/LaunchAgents, created a ~/Library/LaunchAgents folder and copied homebrew.mxcl.postgresql into it.

com.github.facebook.watchman.plist was created for the first time I ran watchman.

Comment: I've been facing this problem for several months, you are awesome! To contribute the react-native community there is an IDE that seems to be great, check [deco](www.decosoftware.com)

Comment: Deco looks interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The directory is stored in wrong location, so remove it :

```
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Create the directory :

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

than safely re-enable the mysql launch :

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Comment: if your expo simulator shows error regarding watchman or Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist for write: Not a directory. you can use this method